# Android - NullPointerException & RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am currently working on my senior project which involves getting data from the database and storing it then showing it on the App. So I've been having issues lately with the code returning mainly two errors:

1. `RuntimeException:` not sure what's causing this
2. `NullPointerException:` as a result of busList array returning empty

Here's my code:

> Activity: ShowResults.java

```
public class ShowResults extends ActionBarActivity {
private static Connection connection = null;
private static String[] busList;
public double lat=24.197910, lon=55.678712;
public static double[][] locCoords = {{24.214649, 55.705841},
        {24.340635, 55.477802}, {24.221663, 55.692266},
        {24.195968, 55.682879}, {24.196066, 55.679534}, {24.197910, 55.678712}, {24.198966, 55.677567}, {24.199936, 55.677314}, {24.200635, 55.677801}};
public static String[] BldNames = {"Saih Bin Ammar Hostel", "Kowaitat Hostel", "Markhaniah Hostel",
        "F3 Building", "F1 Building/The labs", "CIT Building",
        "H4 Building", "Crescent Building",
        "H2/H3 Buildings", "User Current Location"};

//1.jdbc driver name
private static String SQL_JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
// 2. Database URL, V_UDAY\FRAMEWORK is ServerName and JSF is DataBase name
private static String URL
        = "jdbc:sqlserver://NCMSVTRNSDB.aa.uaeu.ac.ae;databaseName=busTable";
//3.Database credentials
private static String USERNAME = "username";//UserName
private static String PASSWORD = "pass";//Password
public static String[] arr;
public static Connection getLocalConnection(double cLat,double cLon) {
    //   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("l.txt");
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(SQL_JDBC_DRIVER);// Register jdbc driver
        //4. open a connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "Select ID, NAME, DT_UPDATE,LON,LAT From mobile";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        String result = "";
        busList = new String[128];//
        int i = 0;
        double dist;
        double l,l2;
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Retrieve by column name
            String id = rs.getString("ID");
            String name = rs.getString("NAME");
            String first = rs.getString("DT_UPDATE");
            String lat = rs.getString("LAT");
            String lon = rs.getString("LON");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            String current = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            if (isCurrent(first) == true) {
                if (name.contains("Hyundai") || name.contains("Coaster")) {
                    result = "Bus:" + name + "\nTime:" + first + "\n" + calcTime(first, current);
                    l = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    l2 = Double.parseDouble(lon);
                    dist = calcDist(cLat, cLon, l, l2);
                    result += "\nDistance: " + dist;
                    result += "\nClosest Building: " + closestBldg(l, l2);
                    result += "\n On/Off Campus: " + onOffCampus(l, l2);
                    busList[i] = result;
                }
                i++;
            }
            else{
                result = "Bus:" + name + "\nTime:" + first + "\n" + calcTime(first, current);
                l = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                l2 = Double.parseDouble(lon);
                dist = calcDist(24.197910, 55.678712, l, l2);
                result += "\nDistance: " + dist;
                result += "\nClosest Building: " + closestBldg(l, l2);
                result += "\n Om/Off Campus: " + onOffCampus(l, l2);
                busList[i] = result;
            }
        }
        //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        setConnectionClose();
        System.out.println("Database Connection Closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Exception in getLocalConeection() " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}

public static void setConnectionClose() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}
public static boolean isCurrent(String busTime) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    String current = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = sdf.parse(current);
        d2 = sdf.parse(busTime);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        if (diffDays == 0 && diffHours <= 1 && (diffMinutes <= 59 && diffMinutes >= 0) && diffSeconds >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
public static String[] getBusList(){
    return busList;
}
public static double calcDist(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double R = 6371000;
    double theta1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double theta2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double thetaDiff = Math.toRadians(theta2 - theta1);
    double lambdaDiff = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(thetaDiff / 2),2)
            + Math.cos(theta1) * Math.cos(theta2)
            * Math.sin(lambdaDiff / 2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(lambdaDiff / 2),2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = R * c;
    return d;
}

public static String calcTime(String time1, String time2) throws ParseException {
    String result;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = null,date2=null;
    try {
        date1 = format.parse(time1);
        date2 = format.parse(time2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    long secs = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long mins = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long hrs = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    if (hrs > 0 && mins > 0 && secs >= 0) {
        result = "ETA: " + hrs + " Hours, " + mins + " Minutes" + " and " + secs + " Seconds";
    } else if (mins > 0 && secs >= 0) {
        result = "ETA: " + mins + " Minutes" + " and " + secs + " Seconds";
    } else if (secs >= 0.01) {
        result = "ETA: " + secs + " Seconds";
    } else {
        result = "ETA: " + "The bus should be here";
    }
    return result;
}


public static String onOffCampus(double busLat, double busLon) {
    double uniLat1 = 24.197690, uniLon1 = 55.677708;
    double uniLat2 = 24.198316, uniLon2 = 55.685948;
    double distToUni1 = calcDist(uniLat1, uniLon1, busLat, busLon);
    System.out.println(distToUni1);

    double distToUni2 = calcDist(uniLat2, uniLon2, busLat, busLon);
    System.out.println(distToUni2);
    if (distToUni1 <= 0.639822725733094 || distToUni2 <= 0.588121032252993) {
        return "On";
    }
    return "Off";
}
public static String closestBldg(double busLat, double busLon) {
    double dist, lat1, lon1, min;
    int mi = 0;
    lat1 = locCoords[0][0];
    lon1 = locCoords[0][1];
    min = calcDist(lat1, lon1, busLat, busLon);

    for (int k = 1; k < locCoords.length; k++) {

        lat1 = locCoords[k][0];
        lon1 = locCoords[k][1];
        dist = calcDist(lat1, lon1, busLat, busLon);
        if (dist < min) {
            min = dist;
            mi = k;
        }
    }

    return BldNames[mi];
}
public void populateListView(){

    //build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_show_results, busList);

    //config the list view
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView5);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        if (b.containsKey("lat1")) {
            lat = b.getDouble("lat1");
        }
        if (b.containsKey("lon1")) {
            lon = b.getDouble("lon1");
        }}
    else{
        lat = 24.197910;
        lon=55.678712;
    }
    getIntent().removeExtra("lat1");
    getIntent().removeExtra("lon1");
    getLocalConnection(lat,lon);
    populateListView();
 }
 }
```

> Activity ShowResults XML: activity_show_results.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp.ShowResults">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

> XML for TextView: dat_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

I am sure that busList is empty whenever I call it, and tried to fix it, but couldn't.
and it is the most probable one to be the cause of my NullPointerExcpetion, but don't know what is causing the RuntimeException
Here's the crash report:

```
         --------- beginning of crash
05-16 21:09:15.373    1927-1927/ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp, PID: 1927
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp/ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp.ShowResults}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
            at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
            at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
            at ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp.ShowResults.populateListView(ShowResults.java:235)
            at ae.ac.uaeu.bustrackerapp.ShowResults.onCreate(ShowResults.java:260)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

any help/advice/feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the populateListView(); method when you finish populating busList, if not this one may be null. You should put it at the end of getLocalConnection method.

Also change

```
public void populateListView(){

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dat_item, busList);

   //config the list view
   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView5);
   list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

and

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_results);
      //All your stuff here
    }
```

I test the code above and it works, i think the reason that your listView is empty is because busList is empty.
Here is the code in the populateListView() that worked in my test.

```
public void populateListView() {
    busList = new String[2];
    busList[0] = "test";
    busList[1] = "test1";

    // build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dat_item, busList);

    // config the list view
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView5);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: For this activity, it is the full code just removed the imports at the top

Comment: working on it right now. Edit: still not working, showing the null error again.

Comment: Edit2: tried again and worked, but showing me an empty listView.

Comment: Ok, now we solved the main problem. Are you sure that you are gettings information from the database? plis in the first line of populateListView() add the following Log.e("tag", busList[0]) and tell me if in your logcat you see some value

Comment: It returns the same thing: an empty listView

Comment: What i should search for in my logcat? i can't seem to find anything

Comment: Well, can you tell me if busList has information inside please?

Comment: try my edit please, anyway the problem was solved, its not crashing anymore, the problem is your array information

Comment: Yeah both of my errors have been fixed. Regarding the array what should I look for exactly? and thanks for helping me through this, much appreciated!

Comment: You should be looking if it has information inside, maybe your parse is not working well so the array never fills. Put this in your populateListView() first line, so you know is its not working well the parse.   if (busList[0].isEmpty()) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "arrayEmpty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
Also, please mark my answer as the correct one :D